# My express application could not connect to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, node.js-connect

Hi i connect my mongodb with command prompt on windows. But i could not with express application. I read too many blog post about node,express and mongodb but could not find the problem. So i need advise.

My database folder : c:/data/db
My mongodb folder: c:/mongodb

In command prompt i type:cd bin
mongod
Then i type: mongo and it says :
[image]

And i can do whatever i want with command prompt.

But when i try to connect mongodb from my node express application i fail always.
My code is shown below:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk('localhost:51241/ecmarketing');
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var collection = db.usercollection.findOne();
res.render('index', { title: 'index' });
};
```

Always i get:

[image]

package.json:

```
{
"name": "application-name",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"start": "node app.js"
},
"dependencies": {
"express": "3.4.4",
"ejs": "~0.8.4",
"ejs-locals": "~1.0.2",
"mongodb": "~1.3.19",
"monk": "~0.7.1"
}
}
```

I installed package with npm install. Also i created ecmarketing file in db folder. Thats all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments:

- are you sure your MongoDB is running on port 51241? The normal port is `27017`;
- with `monk`, you need to explicitly get a reference to the collection:

  ```
  var collection = db.get('usercollection');
  ```
- you don't have to create a folder for the database yourself, MongoDB will do that for you;

Comment: I use default port. I change my query to 
var collection = db.get('usercollection');

But when i write console.log(collection); console give me strange thing. I only want single or multiple user data.

Comment: @fuat you subsequently need to use `find` or `findOne` to query the collection

Comment: When i use findOne console give me strange data like:
{col:
    {manager:{driver:[Object, collections:[Object,options:[Object]},
    driver:
      {emitter:[Object],
       state:1,
       _dbconn:[Object],
       db:null,
       _collections: [Object],
       ObjectID: [Object],
       ...
       ...
    name:'user',
      col: vs vs vs

Comment: @fuat perhaps you should find some examples on how to actually use the monk module